# How to create a glimmer animation like the Google +1 Button onHover

Tags: html, animation, css, webkit

On Google, move your mouse over the faded out +1 button. You'll notice the image animates with a type of glimmer? Like a light going across the image. They are using an image for this but I'd like to know how to do this in CSS3. Any ideas for on hover? Also, anyone know what this effect is called?

Thanks

Comment: +1 I've been wondering the same thing...

Comment: I don't think CSS3 contains this sort of effect, but it is fairly trivial to do using an image sprite and some small javascript.

Here is the image they're using:
http://www.google.com/images/experiments/p1/p1sprite.png

Comment: It does, it's a gradient overlay which is animated across, I'll make a quick jsfiddle.

Comment: @Rikudo, any luck with the jsfiddle? Thanks

Comment: 'fraid not, as stated in my answer, not doable using CSS3 alone at the moment.

Comment: Why can't you animate a CSS3 background gradient?

Answer (score 2):

In their case, they are using a sprite, and then animating through it.
[image: Google Sprite]

Unfortunately, it's not yet possible to animate css3 gradients, and background-position seems to have no effect on it. You'll just have to do with images at the moment.